# Xcode run has linker error when run React Native project

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I upgrade my React Native project from version 0.57 to 0.59.9.
so when I tried to run my ios project in Xcode it occurs an error like below image and I can not find the solution for this problem.

[image]

I try most of the solution in Stackoverflow and Github but this error still stay

Comment: Did you do CMD + OPTION + SHIFT + K (Deep Clean) and delete all folders in Derived Data  in ⁨Users⁩ ▸ ⁨<userName> ▸ ⁨Library⁩ ▸ ⁨Developer⁩ ▸ ⁨Xcode⁩ ?

Comment: @EmreCiftci Yes, I do that but nothings change

Comment: Did you try this? `cd ios => pod install`

Comment: @hongdevelop Yes, I delete and install pod, delete and install node modules, clear cache and etc several time.